# Trying to add dependency json schema using loopback mongodb

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsonschema, loopbackjs, json-schema-validator

I wanted a dependency schema using mongodb loopback.
My Post requests:

REQUEST TYPE 1

```
{
    “url”: “google.com”
    “type”: “redirect”
}
```

REQUEST TYPE 2

```
{
    “url”: “yahoo.com”
    “type”: “anchor”
}
```

My model function looks like

```
 @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  type: string;
        
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    jsonSchema: {
      maxLength: 2000,
      pattern: '^[\\]*$', //using some regex
    },
  })
  url: string;
```

My problem is I want this url pattern to be checked only if type in the payload is redirect.
I read about json schema dependencies. But it is not working. Nor giving any error.
I am trying something like:

```
@property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    jsonSchema: {
    maxLength: 2000,
    "dependencies": {
    if(type == “redirect){
       pattern: '^[\\]*$', //using some regex }
     }
    },
  })
  url: string;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditions in jsonSchema using **dependancies**.

Link : https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/dependencies/

In your case it seems you can use **oneOf**.

Your schema can look like:

```
@property({
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  oneOf: [
    {pattern: 'your 1st pattern'},
    {pattern: 'your 2nd pattern'},
  ],
  jsonSchema: {
    maxLength: 2000,
  },
})
url: string;
```

This schema with oneOf is **valid if exactly one of the subschemas is valid**.

Comment: You are suggesting like if else ?

Comment: I am suggesting one of the pattern should mandatorily match else will throw error.